# React Native FlatList numColumns={2} looks like 3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an FlatList with numColumns={2} but it looks like numColumns={3}. I tried margin: 0 padding: 0 but it is not working.

```js
const ProductListComponent = () => {
    return (
        <View>
            <FlatList
                numColumns={2}
                data={dummyData}
                renderItem={({item}) => {
                    return <ProductButtonComponent text={item.title}/>
                }}
                keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                key={1}
            />
        </View>
    )
}
```

and this is the ProductButtonComponent

```js
const ProductButtonComponent = ({text}) => {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    return (
        <View>
            <Card>
                <Card.Cover source={{ uri: 'https://picsum.photos/700' }} />
                <Card.Title title={text}/>
                <Card.Content>
                    <Paragraph>Card content</Paragraph>
                </Card.Content>
            </Card>
        </View>
    );
}
```

ProductsScreen

```js
const ProductsScreen = () => {
    return (
        <View>
            <ProductListComponent/>
        </View>
    )
}
```

i am using react-native-paper for styling. Note: i tried normal react components but it makes this too.

Result:
[result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaS3p.png)

Comment: Can you add the code where you called the ProductListComponent component.

Comment: The issue isn't with you Flatlist but your component

Comment: you need to style the view in ```ProductButtonComponent```, for example give it width of ```width: 48%```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to style your views and flat list like below. I share returning jsx for each one as an example.

**ProductsScreen**

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <ProductListComponent/>
</View>
```

**ProductListComponent**

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <FlatList
    renderItem={({item}) => {
      return <ProductButtonComponent text={item.title}/>
    }}
    data={dummyData}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    numColumns={2}
    key={1}
    style={{flex: 1}}    
  />
</View>
```

**ProductButtonComponent**

```
<View style={{width: 108, height: 108}}>
  <Card>
    <Card.Cover source={{ uri: 'https://picsum.photos/700' }} />
    <Card.Title title={text}/>
    <Card.Content>
      <Paragraph>Card content</Paragraph>
    </Card.Content>
  </Card>
</View>
```